# Cvlib not showing boxes, labels and confidence

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, cvlib

I am trying to replicate a simple object detection that I found in on [website](https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-with-less-than-10-lines-of-code-using-python-2d28eebc5b11).

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox

im = cv2.imread('downloads.jpeg')
bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(im)
output_image = draw_bbox(im, bbox, label, conf)
plt.imshow(output_image)
plt.show()
```

All required libraries are installed and there are no errors running the code. However, it does not show the output image with the boxes, labels and confidence. How do I fix it?

[image: Output image]

Comment: cvlib downloads the pre-trained weights and caches it in .cvlib folder. Maybe the file got corrupted. Try removing the folder and run again. You can use this command rm -rf ~/. cvlib

Comment: @ArunPonnusamy Wow thanks, It worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
#After loading an image use an assert:
img = cv2.imread('downloads.jpeg')

assert not isinstance(img,type(None)), 'image not found'
```